# I want to login only by using x509 authentication in mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, authentication, ssl, x509

Entries from my config file:

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  tls:
      mode: requireTLS
      certificateKeyFile: D:\certnew\MongoDb\Test3\test-server.pem
      CAFile: D:\certnew\MongoDb\Test3\test-ca.pem

security:
  authorization: enabled
  clusterAuthMode: x509
```

Trying to connect with server Certificate:

```
mongosh --tls --tlsCertificateKeyFile D:\certnew\MongoDb\Test3\test-server.pem --tlsCAFile D:\certnew\MongoDb\Test3\test-ca.pem
```

Trying to connect with Client Certificate:

```
mongosh --tls --tlsCertificateKeyFile D:\certnew\MongoDb\Test3\test-client.pem --tlsCAFile D:\certnew\MongoDb\Test3\test-ca.pem
```

Trying to connect with x509 Auth:

```
mongosh --tls --tlsCertificateKeyFile D:\certnew\MongoDb\Test3\test-client.pem --tlsCAFile D:\certnew\MongoDb\Test3\test-ca.pem --authenticationDatabase '$external' --authenticationMechanism MONGODB-X509
```

I am able to connect in all these above mentioned methods but I want only x509 authentication and other methods should not be allowed.

Comment: What is the user you created? What are the properties of your certificates, check with `openssl x509 -in test-client.pem -noout -subject -ext extendedKeyUsage,keyUsage` and `openssl x509 -in test-server.pem -noout -subject -ext extendedKeyUsage,keyUsage`

Answer (score 0):

You must distinct between **connecting** and **authentication** to your MongoDB.

Your first and second command only connects to your MongoDB, but you are not authenticated. If you try to run a command, then you will get a "not authenticated" error. You can only run commands like `db.help()`, `db.listCommands()` or of course `db.auth(username, password)` to authenticate on the current connection.

You can check current authentication with

```
test> db.runCommand({ connectionStatus: 1 })
{
  authInfo: { authenticatedUsers: [], authenticatedUserRoles: [] },
  ok: 1
}
```

The third command connects and authenticates to your database.

Note, I assume you are running a stand-alone MongoDB, not a Replica Set or Sharded Cluster. In this case `security.clusterAuthMode: x509` has no effect, you can skip it.

You can enforce a client certificate with this setting:

```
net:
  tls:
    mode: requireTLS
    certificateKeyFile: D:\certnew\MongoDb\Test3\test-server.pem
    CAFile: D:\certnew\MongoDb\Test3\client-ca.pem
    allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: false
```

A connection without certificate will be rejected:

```
mongosh --tls --tlsCAFile server-ca.pem
MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 127.0.0.1:27017 closed
```